# How to create only view after already created controller and model on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Everyone,

I want to only make a `View` after I've already created `Controller` and `Model`.

For Example, I've made a Model named `Product` and a Controller named `Order` via the below command.

```
rails g controller Order show
rails g model Product
```

But, I want to add a view which will be named list after crated Model and Controller. 
And, I need to proceed all independent work which is related with the created view file.

Would you like to tell me how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You've created a controller named `Order` with an action method called `show`. Therefore, I'm assuming you want to create a view for `show`.

To do this: create a file called `show.html.erb` in the `app/views/order` folder and add your HTML code in that file. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly Response. Have great Holiday

Answer (score 1):

Although I always create views manually, there is a generator called **erb:controller** if you really want to do it by a generator.

```
$ rails g erb:controller Order show 
create  app/views/order
create  app/views/order/show.html.erb
```

BTW, you can use `rails g -h` to see all generators which you can use.

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly my question point. May I ask one more question ?

Comment: Will this way be able to make another configuration If I will use this way ?  for Example, configuration of config/routes.rb

Because, I already tried this way which guided me, Not apply any configure to config/route.rb file.

Would you like know me how to apply like this implement if it's exist.

Comment: As far as I know, some generators also modify the routes file, such as scaffold or resource, but I don't know how to modify the routes only. Actually the routes modification in this two generators is simple(just insert a "resource" line in the route), maybe you can write a script or create your own generator to do it automatically.

Comment: I appreciate your kindly response. Happy Holiday in your country.

Comment: This is the best answer!